# SQLCMD stops at first GO it reaches in script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

Essentially i need to run a quite large SQL script that wont run in SSMS.

Using sqlcmd to input a  .sql file however will simply seem to stop at first `GO` statement it reaches.

All it seems to run is:

```
USE [master]
GO
```

CMD  writes: "Changed database context to 'master'"

And then its idle, no cpu usage and bare minimal ram usage.

Even with minimized script just to create a new, empty DB, the result is the same.

the string i used would be like this:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -U x -P x -i D:\x\f.sql
```

it connects  to the db just fine, however the included .sql script still wont run.

Setting errorlevel to 1 wont help, it still   stops/halts, simply no message then.

Comment: I suspect your diagnosis is at fault. For starters, the statement "SQL script that wont run in SSMS" needs looking into. And the [`GO` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is explicitly part of `SQLCMD`: "GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the **sqlcmd** and..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think you've got GO in the wrong place.**

I use sqlcmd for a unattended installs and have reproduced the issue and see what you mean.

This is how I call scripts passing parameters:

```
sqlcmd -S . -E -b -v Database="Test" -i "C:\temp\CreateDatabase.sql"
```

This is the CreateDatabase.sql script file:

```
:On Error exit
--:Out null
--:SetVar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 18

-- USE [master] GO -- with this line it fails, but its in the Master context already    

DECLARE @Database varchar(64);
DECLARE @Error int;
DECLARE @Path varchar(256);
DECLARE @BackUpPath varchar(256);

SET @Database = '$(Database)';
SET @Path = '';
SET @BackUpPath = '';   

IF @Path IS NULL OR RTrim(@Path) = ''
    SET @Path = (SELECT SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1, CHARINDEX('master.mdf', LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)
                FROM master.sys.master_files
                WHERE database_id = 1 AND file_id = 1);
ELSE IF Right(@Path, 1) != ''
    SET @Path = @Path + '';

IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] as [Database]
        FROM master.sys.databases
        WHERE [name] = @Database)
    RAISERROR ('Database already exists.', 18, 10); --  :Exit(SELECT 10)

EXECUTE('CREATE DATABASE ' + @Database + ' ON PRIMARY 
        (NAME = ' + @Database + ', FILENAME = ''' + @Path + @Database + '.mdf'', FILEGROWTH = 1024KB)
        LOG ON
        (NAME = ' + @Database + '_log, FILENAME = ''' + @Path + @Database + '_log.ldf'', SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
        COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI');

IF @@Error != 0
    RAISERROR ('Failed to create database.', 18, 12);   --  :Exit(SELECT 2)
```

So you dont need to use GO when creating a database.

When creating the schema and populating your database I would suggest using SQL tools to export the script so you end up with scripts that look like this:

```
USE [SpecificDatabase]


/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_tblAppCustomers_tblCustomers]    Script Date: 11/23/2008 12:44:26 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tblAppCustomers_tblCustomers]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblAppCustomers]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAppCustomers] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAppCustomers_tblCustomers]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_tblAppSales_tblGS]    Script Date: 11/23/2008 12:44:26 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_tblAppSales_tblGS]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tblAppSales]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblAppSales] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_tblAppSales_tblGS]
GO
```

Comment: i did export it with the Generate script in 2008 R2, so it end up with the .sql that does use GO, The scripts are in size of 500- 1.2GB so manually editing and splitting up would be insane work.